# httpUtility Vs window application

Tags: asp.net, windows, vb.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

How to use httpUtility.encode and decode in window application. I implemented a window application. This application use web request to web server. The web server response http encode version. So, How I decode in window application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the reference System.Web to your project.

Then it's...

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("Hello <b>Bob</b>");
```